# How to get api reponse error and error message

Tags: javascript

I'm new to using APIs so some help would be appreciated. I'm posting some data from a form using an API post request. I now need to display a message if this fails, depending on the error and status code.
I know I can get the status code like `response.status` but I also need to get the error itself and/or the error message.

So I'd need something like this

```
   $.ajax(settings).fail(function (response) {
     if(response.status === 404 && response.error === 'example_error'){
      alert('This failed.')
     }
   });
```

I also tried to get it something like this `respsonse.json()` but no luck.
The network response in the console looks like this

```
{"error":"example_error","message":"this is an error"}
```

My API call looks like this:

```
const formData = new FormData(thisForm).entries()

    var settings = {
      "url": "{{ section.settings.endpoint }}",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "data": JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
    };
    
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      alert('success')

      form.reset()
    });
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `console.log(response)` and see what you got

Comment: If the error you get is `example_error`, the issue is with the server you're making the POST request to, not your own JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is not executing the alert block because the "status" property does not exists on the response object. You've got only "error" and "message". Your answer lies in your api's controllers, where you should take care of sending an appropiate http response, and not just a plain object, which it will carry some error message in case of a failure or a success message too.

So, it all depends in which technology you are using in the backend and return an http response from your controllers, each technology would hand to you some methods to return those responses you need, which will carry a status code and other information.

For further learning you can look up for the anatomy of a http response and the official documentation of your backend tech about sending http responses.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you simply console.log() the response and explore it, every object in js is a JSON object.

This looks quite old school, I suggest you use axios instead of ajax, in combination with promises.
It's way easier :))

```
import axios from "axios";
import { config } from "../../configuration/config";

export function sendNotification(message: string): Promise<void> {
  return axios.post(
    `${config.http.servicesUrl}/notify/notifications`,
    {
      message,
    },
    {
      validateStatus: (status) =>
        (status >= 200 && status < 300) || status == 404,
    }
  );
}
```